# Can't remove Flatpak software application

Tags: apt, software-uninstall, flatpak

I installed Flatpak from this guide: https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/ and I want to remove it now but this icon [image: Icon image] doesn't go and I can't remove it. Also, I can open that application. It's same with Ubuntu Software.

I tried these commands to remove flatpak:

```
flatpak uninstall --unused

sudo apt-get remove --autoremove flatpak

sudo apt-get purge flatpak
```

I restart my computer, I tried this commands to remove that application:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

It said "gnome-software-plugin-flatpak" was not installed.

I also checked repositories and didn't see anything. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Where do you find that icon ? In 20.04, the default interface to install apps is no longer Gnome software but Ubuntu's Snap store. What happens if you try to launch gnome-software from a terminal ?

Comment: @CosminSaveanu Okay, thank you. The reason that I can't remove the application was I didn't know the package name. Thanks to you, gnome-software was the correct package name. Now I removed it easily. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove `gnome-software-center`, which is the regular `deb` version of the software center.

```
sudo apt remove gnome-software-center
```

To revert to the default software center of Ubuntu 20.04, install snap-store back:

```
snap install snap-store
```