# Can't remove flatpak software application anyway

Tags: flatpak, gnome-software

I'm sorry I know there is another question like that here [Can't remove Flatpak software application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276653/cant-remove-flatpak-software-application). It is also already answered, nonetheless I couldn't figure out the solution from there. I also couldn't comment because of the privilege (I'm new) so I ask there again. Basically I installed flatpak but then I decided to remove it. I followed the instruction from here [How to completely remove flatpak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174596/how-to-completely-remove-flatpak) so:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak uninstall --all
sudo apt purge --autoremove flatpak
```

but the flatpak app remains and if i run gnome-software on terminal that's the one that open up, not snap.

Could someone help me?